# How to create dictionary when reading csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got the following brute force code:

```
import csv
d = {}
with open(csv_filename, 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        d[key] = np.array(
            [[float(x) for x in row[1:4]], [float(x) for x in row[4:7]],
             [float(x) for x in row[7:]]], dtype=float)
```

Is there a way to rewrite it to avoid `[1:4], [4:7]` etc?

Comment: This is dependent on your csv file. What does your csv file look like? What does your code try to accomplish (brute force or not)? We're missing some context here. :(

Comment: @TrebledJ Well, it's the first column is a key (type: string) and the others are 9 coordinates (floats) that I want to store as a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't seem to see any brute force. I think you're referring to [*hard-code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding)? Generally, neither reading lines of a file nor using constants are considered brute force. Unless the columns of your csv file are dynamic, I wouldn't worry about the constants. (Maybe some comments instead? `# slice key columns` `# slice float columns`)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you just need to reshape the data.

```py
key = row[0]
d[key] = np.reshape(np.array(row).astype(float), (3, 3))
```